# What does this control called?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I am trying to create a control in WPF, that looks like in picture below:

[image]

I have seen this (Location Pane) in **WinMerge** application. User can scroll up/down the blue rectanguar box in th eLocation Pane to see the differences in files. The files on right also scrolls to show the area selected under the blue box. The scrollbar in the right and the blue box are in synch.

Do anyone have idea what this control is called so that I could find this online or create it by myself.

Comment: It's probably a custom control or maybe even just a scrollbar with an overlay on top.

Comment: This control doesn't exist out of the box in wpf. You'll have to create it.

Answer (score 0):

It's a custom scroll bar with extended width and color differences. Similar examples are:

1. Diff Merge - http://sourcegear.com/diffmerge/
2. TfsPendingChangesMargin Visual Studio Extension- https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=AlekseyNagovitsyn.TfsPendingChangesMargin